# VPN on top of Certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, vpn

Our school recently needed us to install a certificate on our own computers in order to connect to the internet. If I use a VPN on top of that, will they be able see what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a TLS tunnel vpn (with simple web auth) Yes.  They will be able to see it, as I'm assuming they're breaking your TLS connections and inspecting the traffic.  I realize this is intrusive, but this is a fairly typical bargain: schools (and big companies) do give you internet access and do this in order to protect themselves from prosecution, and loss of data.

I would suggest you use a different network if you want your communication to be private from your school (and if you have the certificate authority on your phone or personal device, remove it if you want privacy of any sort even off their network.)

If you were able to use something that has it's own transport layer that wasn't tls (eg. IPSEC) you could then connect and the vpn traffic would be encrypted and unable to be read (though that there was traffic, how much - when etc would still be there, just not to where, or what was in the tunnel.)

Comment: I'm reading the question in the way that OP wants to use a VPN over the "compromised" TLS connection. In that case the VPN traffic wouldn't leak.

Comment: So like TLS on TLS tunnel?   I suppose that's feasible if the reverse proxy that's doing the job doesn't mangle the traffic really badly (it probably does) or block "unknown" protocol traffic.

Comment: Yes, sort of. I don't see how the question otherwise would make sense.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to make more sense.